# Record lookup missing fields from record, visual flow

Tags: visual-workflow

In a visual flow I am doing a record lookup on the opportunity object. I set the object as opportunity and when I am entering the filter criteria, the field I am looking for is not an option.

I have confirmed that the field exists. It is a formula field, but other formula fields are available. I can't find any difference between the two fields.

This happens in all flows, edited or new.

It works fine in a sandbox I spun up a few months ago, so maybe it's a system change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the fields that I couldn't find were fields that I had previously moved over from the sandbox to production. The field-level security for those fields were all set to hidden. I must have deployed incorrectly somewhere.

I'm not 100% sure but to deploy correctly you either have to include the profiles that need access. The very bottom answer here seems to be of use. https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gue7AAA